# Bit fetching with type punning. Unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, structure, bit, type-punning

##### Expected result

The program simply prints *anyNum* in its binary representation.
We accomplish this by "front popping" the first bit of value and sending it to standard output.
After ≤32 iterations *i* (=*anyNum*) will finally fall down to zero. Loop ends.

##### Problem

The **v1** version of this code produces the expected result (111...),
However, in **v2**, when I used a *mask* structure to get the first bit, it worked as if the last bit was grabbed (1000...).
Maybe not the last? Anyway why and what is happing in second version of the code?

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct{
  unsigned b31:   1;
  unsigned rest:  31;
} mask;

int main()
{  
  constexpr unsigned anyNum= -1; //0b111...
  for (unsigned i= anyNum; i; i<<=1){
    unsigned bit;
    //bit= (i>>31); //v1
    bit= ((mask*)&i)->b31;  //v2 (unexpected behaviour)
    std::cout <<bit;
  }
}
```

##### Environment

- IDE & platform: https://replit.com/
- Platform: Linux-5.11.0-1029-gcp-x86_64-with-glibc2.27
- Machine: x86_64
- Compilaltion command: **clang++-7** -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp

Comment: Type-punning through unrelated pointers are almost generally *undefined behavior* in C++, as it breaks *strict aliasing*.

Comment: You also have to consider [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) when type-punning through pointers.

Comment: You can type-prune safely with bit_cast: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast if you upgrade to C++20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unsigned b31:   1;` is the least significant bit.

> Maybe not the last?

The last.

> why

Because the compiler chose to do so. The order is whatever compiler decides to.

For example, on GCC the order of bits in bitfields is controlled with [BITS_BIG_ENDIAN](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Storage-Layout.html) *configuration* options.

[x86 ABI](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.98.pdf) specifies that `bit-fields are allocated from right to left`.

> what is happing in second version of the code?

**Undefined behavior**, as in, the code is **invalid**. You should *not expect* the code to do anything sane. The compiler happens to generate code that is printing the least significant bit from `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @KamilCuk I found the answer.
It was enough to do a little line-swap in the code so as to repair it.
With comments I've marked the memory layouts of `struct` (LTR) and bit layout of `unsigned int` (RLT – Little endian).
Not taking them to account was my mistake.

```
#include <iostream>

//struct uses left-to-right memory layout
typedef struct{
  //I've swapped the next 2 lines as a correction.
  unsigned rest:  31;
  unsigned b31:   1; //NOW `b31` is the most significant bit.
} mask;

int main()
{
  //unsigned is Little Endian on Linux-5.11.0-1029-gcp-x86_64-with-glibc2.27
  //,which is right-to-left bit layout.
  constexpr unsigned anyNum= -1; //0b111...
  for (unsigned i= anyNum; i; i<<=1){
    unsigned bit;
    //bit= (i>>31); //v1
    bit= ((mask*)&i)->b31;  //v2 (NOW expected behaviour)
    std::cout <<bit;
  }
}
```